# Is there function that setting a deadline in CSS transiton? without JS

Tags: html, css, frontend

In my code, the left border should be removed after .6s even when the cursor is still(hover) on the button

```
.button {
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.button::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 0%;
    border-left: 1.5px solid black;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

.button:hover:after {
transition: .6s;
height: 100%;
/*After hover(after.6s), height should be 0%*/

}
```

Comment: You can use ```keyframes``` for this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Answer (score 0):

You can use **callback** function to fetch the end of a transition/animation.
Check out this article:

https://betterprogramming.pub/detecting-the-end-of-css-transition-events-in-javascript-8653ae230dc7

Comment: I meant without JS

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @prettyInPink, Here is how you can use `keyframes`.

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.button::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0%;
  border-left: 1.5px solid black;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.button:hover:after {
  /**
     Added 1.2s to smoothly hide the border
     From 0%-50% - .6s
     From 50%-100% - .6s
  **/
  animation: borderAnim 1.2s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes borderAnim {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 0%;   
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="button">My Button</button>
```